# Playing multiple songs in Action script3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have five buttons which contains five songs.then i have one play button and stop button.Now when i click on one song button and then by clicking the play button,the corresponding song should play.wen i press the stop button,the song should stop.Again wen i select different song and click on play button,that specified song should play.i'm using the code given below,but i'm unable get the output. please help me out...!!

```
sng1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mclick);
sng2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mclick);
sng3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mclick);
sng4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mclick);
sng5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mclick);
var url:String;
function mclick(e:MouseEvent)
{
        //private var url:String = "FIFA Theme song.mp3";
        if(e.currentTarget.name == "sng1")
        {
             url="Ippadi Mazhai.mp3";
        }
        else if (e.currentTarget.name == "sng2")
        {
             url = "06 Gore Gore.mp3";
        }
        else if (e.currentTarget.name == "sng3")
        {
             url = "FIFA Theme song.mp3";
        }
        else if (e.currentTarget.name == "sng4")
        {
             url = "babe.mp3";
        }
        else if (e.currentTarget.name == "sng5")
        {
             url = "fast_and_furious_5.mp3";
        }

}
        public class audio extends Sprite{
        private var song:SoundChannel;
        private var soundFactory:Sound;
        public function audio() {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

            soundFactory = new Sound();
            soundFactory.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            soundFactory.addEventListener(Event.ID3, id3Handler);
            soundFactory.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
            soundFactory.load(request);
            song = soundFactory.play();
            plybtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, plClick);
            stpbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stpClick);
        }
        private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
            trace("completeHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function id3Handler(event:Event):void {
            trace("id3Handler: " + event);
        }

        private function ioErrorHandler(event:Event):void {
            trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
            trace("progressHandler: " + event);
        }
        private function plClick(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
             song = soundFactory.play();
        }
        private function stpClick(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
             song.stop();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to just change the `url` in order for the following code to work, you need a `new audio()` statement that will actually load up that sound and play it. A correct way would be if you would initialize all 5 `audio` objects with all 5 different URLs, they will all be in stopped condition, then you display them and click their buttons.